# Python: Sliding Window to compare words in my list with words in the given lexicon

Tags: python, sliding-window

I want to use slide window to check if the word in the 'document' is matched with the word in the 'lexicon'. 
**My question is: which main function is doing this kind of thing? I saw several sliding window example and it seems that they are not what I want.**

```
document=['hello','my','world','love'], lexicon=['questions','hello','shift',.....]
```

If I use slide window with size set to 3. Does that mean I will get

```
('hello','my','world') and ('my','world','love')
```

For each, I wanna test if

```
'hello','my','world'
```

are in the lexicon separately, and then test if

```
'hello my','my world', 'hello world'
```

are in the lexicon separately, and test if

```
'hello my world'
```

is in the lexicon.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @PauloBu My question is which main function is doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools 

document=['hello','my','world','love']

for x in range(len(document)-2):
    words = document[x:x+3]
    print 'words:', words

    print "--- 1 ---"
    for y in itertools.combinations(words,1):
        print ' '.join(y)

    print "--- 2 ---"
    for y in itertools.combinations(words,2):
        print ' '.join(y)

    print "--- 3 ---"
    print ' '.join(words)

    print "-----------------"
```

result

```
words: ['hello', 'my', 'world']
--- 1 ---
hello
my
world
--- 2 ---
hello my
hello world
my world
--- 3 ---
hello my world
-----------------
words: ['my', 'world', 'love']
--- 1 ---
my
world
love
--- 2 ---
my world
my love
world love
--- 3 ---
my world love
-----------------
```